# Weird CSS problem :Missing Inline CSS : ActionMailer Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, actionmailer

My ActionMailer involves generating a report and,storing it into a HTML file and sending it as a HTML attachment. I wanted to give it some styling , so I added inline styling that gets written into the HTML file everytime the report is generated .

But the styling does not reflect in the attachment. Interestingly, the generated report when opened locally on my machine reflects the styling. I saw the HTML source of the attachment and the inline css styling is missing. I'm absolutely clueless as to why its happening. 
A heads-up would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionMailer has some very strange ways of operating.  CSS is one of the things it can really fall over with when rendering a template.  Have a look at this solution:

http://devblog.imedo.de/2008/08/05/rails-actionmailer-with-html-layouts-inline-css-and-entity-substitution/